# Accessing HTML element through React and adding onClick effect

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I have a React application, which uses GraphQL to fetch data from backend. Requested data is a html code (content with some divs) built with CMS page editor and rendered using React.

HTML code is rendered using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser

How can I access `<button class="someClass">SUBSCRIBE</button>`  through different react component ? The reason I want to access it through react is that I have a Newsletter module which is responsible for making GQL requests and validating recaptcha, as well as Popup module. The popup should be displayed when we hit SUBSCRIBE - this is why I want to attach onClick to that button.

Should I use `document.getElementsByClassName` in `componentDidMount` ? Or is there a better way to achieve things like this ?

[image: Newsletter box]

Comment: How the HTML markup received from backend is rendered exactly?

Comment: Using https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser